# How can i save the data and softwares inside docker container permanently?

Tags: opencv, docker, vim, permanent

I am using docker image opencv from https://hub.docker.com/r/andrewssobral/bgslibrary_opencv3/
of andrewssobral author.

First, i initialized container of the image by typing command:

**docker run -it -p 5901:5901 andrewssobral/bgslibrary_opencv3 bash**

And i tried install vim by command line:

```
apt-get install vim
```

But when i use ***exit*** COMMAND to go out of the container and i run it again then vim was uninstalled.

**So how do i install vim or another software permanently inside docker?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But when i exit docker above container and i run it again then vim was uninstalled.

This is where the problem is: `docker run` creates a new container.

When you use `docker run ...` a new container is created and started based on the image you provide inside the command. It is also assigned a random `name` (if you don't specify one). If this container exits, you can then use `docker start name` and start it again. This means that if you had previously installed `vim` it will be there.

**Solution:** create a new image which includes what you need.

1. [@Sergiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4519500/sergiu) proposed to use Dockerfile
2. or another way is to save the current state of your container to a new image so that you can use it later on to create new containers with your changes included. To do this you can use [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/)

something like this:

```
docker commit your_modified_container_name [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
```

Comment: yes you could also do as @tgogos suggested :) as on top of the base image that someone did will also 'save' / 'commit' your extra packages / commands

Answer (score 3):

You have two options: or you edit the *Dockerfile* provided by the author to add vim or you create a new *Dockefile* **FROM** the image.